# Cassandra scaling cheat-sheet

Tags: performance, cassandra, scaling

Of course you can only know the performance of your system with your load with your use-cases by ... actually implementing it!  That aside, before embarking on a prototype, I'm searching for some very rough estimates of how Cassandra performs.

For various configurations of nodes and data-centres, and for various read and write consistency levels, what the chances of reading a stale value?  What kind of key reads and writes per second would you expect to sustain, and what kind of latency would each read and write have?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra benchmarking presented at VLDB earlier this year: http://vldb.org/pvldb/vol5/p1724_tilmannrabl_vldb2012.pdf

Performance/consistency tradeoffs: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/your-ideal-performance-consistency-tradeoff

Answer (score 1):

We run an application with 500 datapoints posted per second per web node(we have 6 cassandra nodes).  We could probably get 1000 datapoints per second per node if we cached 100M of data in the client to avoid the read.

the profile of that is using PlayOrm with one findAll(List keys) and one putAll(List entities) on each request where each key in that list is a single data point as the clients send a batch of datapoints over http so we don't have as much http overhead....maybe that gives you some idea at least though not sure.

We have not yet tested the correct ratio of web nodes to cassandra nodes but I suspect it is like my last client where it was near one to one on this project though it changes with the profile.

We run 4 web nodes and get 2000 datapoints per second right now.